# How to divide a circle with two perpendicular chords to minimize (and maximize) the following expression

Tags: geometry

Consider a circle with two perpendicular chords, dividing the circle into four regions $X, Y, Z, W$(labeled):

[image]

What is the maximum and minimum possible value of

$$\frac{A(X) + A(Z)}{A(W) + A(Y)}$$

where $A(I)$ denotes the area of $I$?

I know (instinctively) that the value will be maximum when the two chords will be the diameters of the circle, in that case, the area of the four regions will be equal and the value of the expression will be $1$.

I don't know how to rigorously prove this, however. And I have absolutely no idea about minimizing the expression.

Comment: Why would that be the minimum? Seems to me that the maximum and the minimum must be inverses of each other.

Comment: According to the answer in my book, the maximum is $1$ and the minimum is $\frac{\pi - 2}{\pi + 2}$. And I'm sorry, I actually meant that the maximum value is $1$ and not the minimum. Edited.

Comment: Well, I guess this may be the case if we stick to calling $W$ the one part that contains the center. But it isn't mentioned anywhere in the problem statement. If it's not the rule, we can just reassign letters and turn the value into its inverse.

Comment: You cannot reassign the letters since the expression is not cyclic. Reassigning the letters will change the value of the expression we want to optimize.

Comment: By symmetry, the minimum value will occur when $A(Y)=0$ and $A(X)=A(Z)$. When this happens, the ratio becomes a semicircle minus a right-isosceles triangle to a semicircle plus a right-isosceles triangle (special case of Thales' theorem). That is, $\frac{\frac{\pi r^2}{2} - \frac12 (\sqrt{2}r)^2}{\frac{\pi r^2}{2} + \frac12 (\sqrt{2}r)^2}$.

Comment: @Gerard, I don't think you quite get what I'm saying. It doesn't matter if the expression is cyclic. I never said it was. If we deem as unimportant the fact that $W$ contains the center, then the *picture itself* is sort of cyclic, i.e. if we cyclically reassign letters, we get another valid picture.

Comment: If you don't like reassigning letters, you can slowly rotate the lines containing the chords around point $D$ (but leave the circle where it is). When the rotation reaches $90$ degrees, the value of the target expression will be the inverse of what it was in the beginning.

Comment: Oh, yes. I understand.

Comment: @DavidH: Can you elaborate on your comment, please? What do you mean by 'by symmetry'. That, combined with Dan's input, should give us both the extremal values.

Comment: @Gerard Rewrite the ratio as $\frac{A(X)+A(Z)}{A(Y) + A(W)} = \frac{\pi r^2 - A(Y) - A(W)}{A(Y) + A(W)}$. The ratio is clearly invariant under permutation of X and Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the considered quotient is not constant it has a maximum value $\mu>1$, and the minimum value is then ${1\over \mu}$. I claim that
$$\mu={\pi+2\over\pi-2}\doteq4.504\ ,\tag{1}$$
as conjectured by MvG.

[image]

*Proof.* I'm referring to the above figure. Since the sum of the four areas is constant the  quotient in question is maximal when
$$S(\alpha,p):={\rm area}(X)+{\rm area}(Z)\qquad\left(-{\pi\over2}\leq\alpha\leq {\pi\over2}, \quad 0\leq p\leq1\right)$$
is maximal.

Turning the turnstile around the point $(p,0)$ and looking at the "infinitesimal sectors" so arising we see that
$$\eqalign{{\partial S\over\partial\alpha}&={1\over2}\bigl((r_1^2-r_4^2)+(r_3^2-r_2^2)\bigr)\cr &={1\over2}\bigl((r_1+r_3)^2-(r_4+r_2)^2-\bigr)+(r_2r_4-r_1r_3)\cr &=2\bigl((1-p^2\sin^2\alpha)-(1-p^2\cos^2\alpha)\bigr)+0\cr
&=2p^2(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)\ .  \cr}$$
From this we conclude the following: Starting at $\alpha=-{\pi\over2}$ we have $S={\pi\over2}$, then $S$ decreases for $-{\pi\over2}<\alpha<-{\pi\over4}$, from then on increases until $\alpha={\pi\over4}$, and finally decreases again to $S={\pi\over2}$ at $\alpha={\pi\over2}$. It follows that for the given $p\geq0$ the area $S$ is maximal at $\alpha={\pi\over4}$.

We now fix $\alpha={\pi\over4}$ and move the center $(p,0)$ of the turnstile from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$. Instead of "infinitesimal sectors" we now have "infinitesimal trapezoids" and obtain
$${\partial S\over\partial p}={1\over\sqrt{2}}((r_2+r_3)-(r_1+r_4)\bigr)>0\qquad(0<p\leq1)\ .$$
It follows that $S$ is maximal when $\alpha={\pi\over4}$ and $p=1$. In this case one has $S=1+{\pi\over2}$, which leads to the $\mu$ given in $(1)$.

Comment: Excellent answer. How did you produce the figure?

Comment: Can you give me a link to their website. There are a lot of matches for the name 'canvas'.

Comment: @Gerard: With the drawing program "Canvas", since almost twenty years. Unfortunately Canvas  is no longer supported on Mac OS. – See here:  http://www.acdsee.com/en/products/canvas-14

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the line $BD$ between areas $X\cup Y$ and $W\cup Z$ is always horizontal, so the other chord will always be vertical. You may assume your circle to be the unit circle (since the radius will cancel out of the expression in any case). You can parametrize your whole setup by the coordinates of the intersection between these two chords, namely the point $D=(x,y)$ with $x^2+y^2\le1$. Depending on these coordinates, you can compute the areas described in your question, using [circular segments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) and triangles. I did this using [sage](http://sagemath.org/), and the ugly result looks like this:

```
-(2*x*y - 2*sqrt(-x^2 + 1)*sqrt(-y^2 + 1) + sqrt(2*sqrt(-y^2 + 1)*x -
2*sqrt(-x^2 + 1)*y + 2)*sqrt(-1/2*sqrt(-y^2 + 1)*x + 1/2*sqrt(-x^2 +
1)*y + 1/2) + sqrt(1/2*sqrt(-y^2 + 1)*x - 1/2*sqrt(-x^2 + 1)*y +
1/2)*sqrt(-2*sqrt(-y^2 + 1)*x + 2*sqrt(-x^2 + 1)*y + 2) -
2*arcsin(1/2*sqrt(2*sqrt(-y^2 + 1)*x - 2*sqrt(-x^2 + 1)*y + 2)) -
2*arcsin(1/2*sqrt(-2*sqrt(-y^2 + 1)*x + 2*sqrt(-x^2 + 1)*y + 2)))/(2*x*y
+ 2*sqrt(-x^2 + 1)*sqrt(-y^2 + 1) - sqrt(2*sqrt(-y^2 + 1)*x +
2*sqrt(-x^2 + 1)*y + 2)*sqrt(-1/2*sqrt(-y^2 + 1)*x - 1/2*sqrt(-x^2 +
1)*y + 1/2) - sqrt(1/2*sqrt(-y^2 + 1)*x + 1/2*sqrt(-x^2 + 1)*y +
1/2)*sqrt(-2*sqrt(-y^2 + 1)*x - 2*sqrt(-x^2 + 1)*y + 2) +
2*arcsin(1/2*sqrt(2*sqrt(-y^2 + 1)*x + 2*sqrt(-x^2 + 1)*y + 2)) +
2*arcsin(1/2*sqrt(-2*sqrt(-y^2 + 1)*x - 2*sqrt(-x^2 + 1)*y + 2)))
```

If you had to do things manually, you might want to spend time simplifying this beast, but since all I care about at the moment is visualizing this, I'm fine as long as my computer can deal with it.

You can polot the result. For $x,y\ge0$ the result looks like this:

[image: Ratio, evaluated for a quarter circle]

In the bottom plane you see your quarter circle of all possible locations for $D$, and in the vertical direction you see the value of your fraction. In this image, the maximal value of $1$ can indeed be observed for $D=(0,0)$. But *any* point on a horizontal or vertical line through the origin will yield the same value. So it is sufficient that *one* of the two lines passes through the origin. Which makes sense due to the symmetric way the areas are distributed to numerator and denominator in this case.

The minimal value is “obviously” (although this is no proof!) at $x=y=\frac12\sqrt2$, i.e. half way between these two and at the very rim of the circle. There you get a value of

$$\frac{\pi-2}{\pi+2}\approx 0.222$$

Note that this is the same value [David H](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55051/david-h) already gave in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560929/how-to-divide-a-circle-with-two-perpendicular-chords-to-minimize-and-maximize#comment1190069_560929).

But as comments already pointed out, it is far from obvious that $D$ has to lie in the first quadrant. In other words, if you don't always associate $W$ with the area that contains the origin, then the maximal value will neccessarily be the reciprocal of your minimal value, i.e.

$$\frac{\pi+2}{\pi-2}\approx 4.504$$

To visualize this case with all quadrants included, you can extend the above plot to the following one:

[image: Function value over whole circle]

Since the scales of various areas are so very different, the overall shape might be clearer if you take the logarithms of the fractions you gave. Then you get the following symmetrical result:

[image: Logarithms of function values]

As you are considering ways to proove these facts, looking at the plots might suggests possible approaches. For example, you might be able to argue that looking for a minimum in a quarter circle is enough, since all other cases can be reduced to that one. You might want to use polar coordinates, as the mesh in the above plots suggests. You could try to demonstrate that increasing the radius will always decrese the function value, so that it is sufficient to look at configurations which have $D$ on the circle itself. Then you have a much simpler 1d problem, which should be open to common techniques from calculus.